# how to use onClick() on checkbox in jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp

How do I use the onClick() event within a jsp page on a checkbox. Here is my code and it keeps giving me errors when I have the onClick() event in the code.

JS:

```
function toggleDiv(tokenCheckBox) {     
  if (tokenCheckBox.checked == true) { 
    document.getElementById("CardNo").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("Token").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("CardNo").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("Token").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

JSP:

```
html:checkbox property="returnToken" onClick="toggleDiv(this)"
```

Comment: What are the errors? It seems to work just fine here when running in [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dy43L/)

Comment: I'm using jsp not html. the property returnToken is passed on to a form bean. How can I add the event to the jsp.

Comment: The error that exists when the onClick is added to the html:checkbox is a internal 500 error.

Comment: You will need to provide **WAY** more information if you want people to help...

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this >> `<input type="checkbox" onClick="toggleDiv(this)">`

This is wrong >> `<html:checkbox property="returnToken" onClick="toggleDiv(this)">`

Even if it is JSP, the way you declare HTML remains the same.

Could you please explain how do you use like `<html:checkbox>` ?

Regards,

Comment: This explains it: http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts1/html-checkbox-Tag.shtml

Comment: @user2292805 - No it doesn't.  How do you figure that explains anything?

Comment: @user2292805, dude, they are using user defined jsp tag libraries. That is completely different. You don't need that. Regards,

Comment: Notice that the OP states that the property _returnToken_ should be "_passed on to a form bean_".  This suggests that he wants and needs to use a JSP tag.  We've both guessed wrong!  There is no way we can troubleshoot his "_internal server error_" with literally **zero** relevant information.

Comment: The error only exists when this code is added to the checkbox onClick.

Comment: Java code: FormBean.java - private boolean returnToken;public void public boolean getReturnToken()
     {
         return returnToken;
     }setReturnToken(boolean returnToken)
     {
         this.returnToken = returnToken;
     }                                                        ReportAction.java boolean returnToken = formbean.getReturnToken();
              String value = returnToken ? "N" : "Y";
              reportViewBean.addPair("TOKEN", value); Then this value is passed on to a WebFocus report fex.

Comment: yes using struts, when I add in the onclick the jsp form, it breaks with an internal 500 error, and nothing is in the logs.

Comment: Check whether checkbox is loaded properly with the appropriate property name in the the HTML DOM.

Comment: I went around it and created two input boxes instead of trying to show/hide them based on the checkbox.